# Webform submit buttons redirect to first page when clicked twice

Tags: webforms, forms

Hi I'm relatively new to Drupal 7 and I'm currently working with a multistep webform. I'm having a particular problem around the Previous/Next submit buttons which seem to work fine when clicked ones but when two clicks are performed on any of them with a second or two delay between the clicks (while the form is loading) they do not direct to the previous or next page (depending which button is clicked) but direct to the start of the form. Any idea on how to prevent this from happening. I have tried to disable the buttons (in the hook_form_alter()) after the first click and also tried to put some sort of delay but nothing seems to be successful. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @AnilSagar I was actually just looking at that question. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for Webform module. Please post bugreports in appropriate issue queues, not here.

Comment: @Mołot it isn't a bug report it's a simple question that's why it has been asked before too. (see Anil's comment above)